# How to make extension menu icon adapt Visual Studio theme?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I'm developing a Visual Studio extension that extended menus, and I've added some `.xaml` vector icon to the menu commands.

But Visual Studio has several theme, the prime example are Light and Dark. I can't make an icon that fit both themes at same time.

I found some extensions that can adapt the icon color to different themes. Such as Resharper.

So how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

Visual Studio will auto reverse the color if it's gray.

I just need to make a design that adapt the light theme.